# What do I need to fix this leaky sink?

Tags: leak, sink

My sink started leaking - it looks like I need to replace all of the seal/gasket type things between the basin and the garbage disposal.

Top side:

[image: Top side]

Bottom side:

[image: Bottom side]

I am guessing that the steel part on the top side can be disconnected from the black plastic part, but I don't know that for sure, so I'm not going to go ripping at it until someone on the internet tells me to.

How do I seal each side of this back up?

The model is Pulverator P10. I couldn't find a manual online.

Comment: This wouldn't be a Waste King disposer??  The model number would be helpful.  The method of disassembly is different than the ISE (in sink erator)

Comment: @HerrBag added model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plumbers putty , in a 3/8 in thick rope circle, goes under the top part.

It helps to have a helper push it straight down and keep it from turning while the jamb nut and rubber washer and  (sometimes paper) thrust washer.  The rubber washer goes against the sink.  The thrust washer goes between the rubber washer and the jamb nut.

If someone used some thread dope previously, get the mating surface of the sink cleaned off.

If the rubber washer or the thrust washer is deformed, replace them.

This [video from Anaheim](http://webapps.easy2.com/cm2/flash/generic_index.asp?page_id=35749126) shows the mounting of the "Cushion ring" in step 6

A [locknut wrench](http://reviews.homedepot.com/1999/100162236/steel-strainer-locknut-wrench-reviews/reviews.htm) helps to loosen/tighten the nut.

[image]

This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_2vJYm5ci8) shows replacing an ISE with a Waste King

Comment: So it looks like I just need to get some plumbers putty for now, right?  I don't see how I can even get the whole assembly disconnected enough to replace the washers.

Comment: Ok, I'm at the store now - I'll pick up a new set of washers just in case.

Comment: Waste King disposers appear to use a rubber ring at the bottom of the sink outlet tube (the black plastic) to hold the mounting ring in place 
ISE (In.sink.erator) disposers have a metal wire clip holding on the mounting ring. You pop the clip off with a flat screwdriver and a pair of needle nose pliers. The disposer flange will then drop right off. Be careful popping it off without pliers on it, it will sometimes go flying

Comment: The Pulverator is made by Anaheim manufacturing, makers of the Waste King line

Comment: There was indeed a rubber ring holding everything on the bottom.  I was able to pull that off, give everything a good scrub, replace the washers, and after a fresh pile of plumbers putty everything looks good.  Thanks!

Comment: Happy grinding!